# Need help on Binding objects

Tags: ruby, binding, ruby-2.0

From the [`Binding object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html)

> Objects of class Binding encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use. The variables, ***methods, value of self, and possibly an iterator block that can be accessed in this context are all retained***. Binding objects can be created using Kernel#binding, and **are made available to the callback of Kernel#set_trace_func**.

can anyone help me to understand the fact by single examples of each the bold lines above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Methods:**

```
x = eval("foo", binding) rescue "foo undefined"
puts x

def foo; "foo"; end

puts eval("foo", binding)
```

This outputs:

```
foo undefined
foo
```

**Value of `self`:**

```
puts eval("self", binding)
class Foo
  def eval_self
    eval("self", binding)
  end
end
puts Foo.new.eval_self
```

This outputs:

```
main
#<Foo:0x10c5a3018>
```

**An iterator block:**

```
block = eval("yield", binding) rescue "no iterator block"
puts block

def block
  eval("yield", binding)
end
puts block { "iterator block" }
```

This outputs:

```
no iterator block
iterator block
```

**Kernel#set_trace_func:**

```
class Test
  def test
    a = 1
  end
end

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  puts eval("self", binding)
}
t = Test.new
t.test
```

This outputs:

```
main
Test
#<Test:0x10204cb28>
#<Test:0x10204cb28>
Test
main
#<Test:0x10204cb28>
#<Test:0x10204cb28>
#<Test:0x10204cb28>
main
main
main
```

You can read more about `Kernel#set_trace_func` in its [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func).

Comment: Exactly the one I was searching for. and please explain this also with some tiny examples `Kernel#set_trace_func.`.